# Ellipse of "in which" after "the way"

Tags: ellipses

The term "the way in which" is very common in English texts. But usually "in which" sounds unnecessary to me. Is it accepted/proffered to just omit it.

Example:

> The different you sense between these two must has something to do
>   with the different ways [in which] they are spotlighted.

Comment: Hmm, I was involved in a chat discussion a while back that you might find relevant, starting around here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=33631542#33631542 Specifically, the following PDF seems to discuss "way" without "in which": https://semlab5.sbs.sunysb.edu/~rlarson/larson87mps.pdf

Comment: @sumelic So do you think the ellipse is OK?